# How to print IP address using tcpdump and awk?

Tags: awk, tcpdump

I used this command but I am unable to print multiple values before each '`.`'
This command is only printing the `192` of `192.168.113.2`. I want to print the rest as well in the same line.

```
sudo tcpdump -i 2 -c 20 -n | awk -F '>' '{print $2}' | awk -F ':' '{print $1}' | awk -F '.' '{print $1}'
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the result of `sudo tcpdump -i 2 -c 20 -n`

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo tcpdump -i 2 -c 20 -n | awk -F '>' '/>/{sub(".[^.]*:.*$", "", $2 ); print $2}'
```

Comment: You should never need to pipe awk into awk.